# How do I filter words with a discord bot? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I have recently created a bot for my discord server. Now I want him to filter bad words.

**For example:**

---

User (without bot): You are an asshole

---

User (with bot): You are an [I'm stupid because I swear]

---

Is this even possible in Discord? I have given my bot all permissions! (including removing messages, it can't edit message with the program self tho)

If that is not possible^ Can we do the following?

The ability to directly delete the message and write the following:

---

Bot: @username Do not swear!

---

Now I have the following code (I dont know if useful):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Hello, the bot is online!')
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content === '--Trump'){
        message.reply('He is the president of the United States of 
America!');
    }
    if(message.content === '--Putin'){
        message.reply('He is the president of Russia!');
    }
});

client.login('MzAwMzM5NzAyMD*1NDUxNzc4.C8rH5w.M44LW*nrfbCR_zHzd**vtMqkr6nI');
```

Comment: @André Dion No, thank you for the link! Im quite new to javascript. How van I use that code?

Comment: Please hide your client.login() line. I am pretty sure you don't want people to have random access to your bot if I am correct...

Comment: I have covered it already with some "*"'s

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome). Currently in the Discord API there is no possible way to edit a message from another user. You could completely delete the message or you could resend it but edited. If you want to resend it then you could use:

```
let censor = "[Sorry, I Swear]"; /* Replace this with what you want */
client.on('message', message => {
    let edit = message.content.replace(/asshole/gi, censor);
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send(`${message.author.username}: ${edit}`);
}
```

Input >>> Hello asshole

Output <<< AkiraMiura: Hello [Sorry, I Swear]

Take note that if the user sends a 2000 byte (Charater) long message you won't be able to send a fixed version and it would just get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use Regex to help you detect from blacklisted words you wanted to.

**For example, If you want to blacklist the word `asshol*`, use the regex to detect the word:**

```js
if ((/asshole/gm).test(message.content)) 
  message.delete().then(() => {
    message.reply('Do not swear!'); // Sends: "@user1234 Do not swear!"
  });
}
```

*If you wanted to blacklist/filter MULTIPLE words, like `fu*k` and `sh*t`*

Use separators in Regex: `/(word1|word2|word3)/gm`
So... use:

```js
if ((/(fuck|shit)/gm).test(message.content)) {
    message.delete().then(() => {
      message.reply('Do not swear!');
    });
}
```

It's fully working!

Re-write in **FULL** code,

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if ((/asshole/gm).test(message.content)) {
    message.delete().then(() => {
      message.reply('Do not swear!'); // Sends: "@user1234 Do not swear!"
    });
  }
});
```

Tell me if it works

Good Luck,
Jedi

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    message.edit(message.content.replace(/asshole/gi, "[I'm stupid because I swear]"))
       .then(msg => console.log(`Updated the content of a message from ${msg.author}`))
       .catch(console.error);
});
```

credit to @André Dion for bringing up the right method from the API

Comment: I get this when I type 'asshole': (node:13676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Forbidden

Comment: And your code missed a ')' before the ';' visual studio said.

Comment: @M.Kaçiran corrected and inserted some more promise handling from the API docs

Comment: text: '{"code": 50005, "message": "Cannot edit a message authored by another user"}', 

I think it would not work since the bot has not permissions in the app. Anyways thank you for the help!

Comment: @M.Kaçiran You could still do something like your second approach, deleting the message and tell the user should not swear. Mind upvoting and accepting my answer then?

Comment: Upvoted already, but it is not an answer for people with the same problem. The problem is already solved like you said with deleting the message and then reply with msg.reply!

Comment: @M.Kaçiran well its impossible from the permissions of the api so technically there is no answer to this.