# A Discordjs Chat Filter

Tags: json, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js bot and I was curious how to add a chat filter to it. As in a user says `f***` and it will auto-delete.

Comment: See [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43358283/2341603).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["bad words" filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515/bad-words-filter)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bad-words

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an array of words,

```
var profanities = ["test1", "test2", "..."];
```

then in your bot.on message handler, or how you use to handle messages,

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    let Admin = message.guild.roles.find('name', "Admin"); // Change this to meet what you want
    let General = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "general"); // All text channels are lowecase. Change this to meet what you want
    for (x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
        if(message.member.roles.has(Admin.id) || message.channel.id === General.id) return; // if you changed the name of the variables above, change these too.
        if (msg.includes(profanities[x])){
            await message.reply("You cannot say that here!")     
            message.delete()
            // Your code here
            return;     
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT:
This is very basic, it won't look for substitute letters such as $, @ or numbers/spaces unless you code those directly in, which you can have a list of words then have a console log every word with substitute letters.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, is there any way to make it to where Administrators bypass that? Or is there a way too make it ignore a certain channel?

Comment: Yes, you can check if the sender has a certain role with this code, add it right under "let msg = ..." let *role* = message.guild.roles.find('name', "*Case sensitive role name*") message.member.roles.has(*role*.id), for your convience, I've updated the post

Comment: I also forgot to say, you can check the channel as well! Both have been implemented in the code above, the 2 new variables are what you change. If you change the names of them make sure to do so in the new if statement too

Answer (score 1):

```
const blacklisted = ["word1", "word2", "word3"] // and continue doing this until you have entered all your desired words
client.on("message", message => {
  let shouldDelete = false
  for(word in blacklisted){
    if(message.content.includes(word)) shouldDelete = true
  }
  if(shouldDelete) message.delete()
});
```

Please let me know if I messed up anywhere. This is just how I would do it. (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ChatFilter that is guaranteed to work!

```
bot.on("message", async message => {

  let blacklisted = ['yourbadword1', 'yourbadword2', 'and some more bad words :3'];

let foundInText = false;
for (var i in blacklisted) {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted[i].toLowerCase())) foundInText = true;
}

if(foundInText) {
  message.delete();
  message.channel.send("Stop using this bad word!")
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on("message", async message => {

    //Define the words that should be deleted after a successfull detection
    let blacklisted2 = ['Some', 'Random', 'word'];

    //Set foundInText to false
    let foundInText2 = false;

    //Check for the blacklisted words in blacklisted2
    for (var i in blacklisted2) {

        if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(blacklisted2[i].toLowerCase()))

        //If a blacklisted word has been detected in any sentences, it's going to set foundInText2 to true.
            foundInText2 = true;

    }

    //If something has been detected, delete the message that has a blacklisted word inside of it.
    if (foundInText2) {

        //Delete the message.
        message.delete();

        //Then do whatever you want

    }

});
```

Let me know
if everything works.If you have any problems, contact / answer me here.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a simple way e.g

```
let badwords = ['word1', 'word2']
client.on('message', async (message) => {
            if (badwords.includes(message.content.toLowerCase())) {
                message.delete();
                message.channel.send(`HEY! you cant send that here`);
            }
        })
```

this is a filter that i use for my bot. It first turns the message into lowercase then searches for the word in the array. If it finds the word is matching the word in the lowercase message then the message is deleted. BTW words in the array have to be lowercase for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
client.on('message', message => {
    message.delete(message.content.replace(/asshole/gi))
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

This is just a example you can make it, with a text array too.